# Find parameter which solves a 9-by-9 homogeneous system of linear equations, NSolve gives some incorrect answers

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

I have a set of 9 linear homogeneous simultaneous equations which depend on 2 parameters, p and x. For a chosen value of p, I aim to calculate the smallest 3 values of x which satisfy the simultaneous equations. I run into trouble when plotting x as a function of p, which I think is down me using NSolve incorrectly.

### Background functions for the problem

The elements which form the coefficient matrix for this problem are in turn calculated from the eigenfunctions/values from another square matrix, given below:

```
ClearAll[eigs, value1, func1, value2, func2]
g = 1.006;
ham[p_] := SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> Table[i^2, {i, -9, 9}], Band[{2, 1}] -> p*100*(1 - g), Band[{1, 2}] -> p*100*(1 - g), Band[{3, 1}] -> p*(g/2), Band[{1, 3}] -> p*(g/2)}, {19, 19}] 
(* 19x19 Matrix from which I find eigenfunctions and eigenvalues which will later contribute to my system of simultaneous equations. I will need eigenfunctions and values for both ham[p] and ham[-p]. *)

eigs[p_] := eigs[p] = SortBy[Transpose[Eigensystem[ham[p]]], First] (* Eigenvalues of the above matrix, ordered with smallest eigenvalue listed first. *)
value1[p_, n_] := value1[p, n] = eigs[p][[n]][[1]] (* Eigenvalues *)
func1[p_, n_] := func1[p, n] = Chop[(1/Sqrt[2*Pi])*eigs[p][[n]][[2]]] . Table[Exp[I*j*\[CurlyPhi]], {j, -9, 9}] (* Function constructed as an exponential series with the eigenvector elements as coefficients. *)
value2[p_, n_] := value2[p, n] = value1[-p, n] (* Eigenvalues for matrix ham[-p] *)
func2[p_, n_] := func2[p, n] = func1[-p, n] (* Similar to func1 but for eigenvectors from ham[-p] *)
```

### Coefficient matrix for system of linear equations

I define here the coefficient matrix for the homogeneous set of linear equations I wish to solve. Its a 9-by-9 matrix, which I input manually. Each element is formed by a numerical integral involving funk1 & func2, multiplied by a prefactor involving value1 and value2. I apologise in advance if this is an eyesore:

```
Clear[coeff]

me[(p_)?NumericQ, x_, (n0_)?NumericQ, (M0_)?NumericQ, (n_)?NumericQ,(M_)?NumericQ] := Chop[
((0.4*Pi)/(value1[p, n] + value2[p, M] - x))*
NIntegrate[func1[p, n]*func2[p, M]*Conjugate[func1[p, n0]]*Conjugate[func2[p, M0]], {\[CurlyPhi], -Pi, Pi},
AccuracyGoal -> 6, Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", Method -> "GaussKronrodRule", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]]; 

coeff[p_, x_] := coeff[p, x] = {
{me[p, x, 1, 1, 1, 1] - 1, me[p, x, 1, 1, 1, 2], me[p, x, 1, 1, 1, 3], me[p, x, 1, 1, 2, 1], me[p, x, 1, 1, 2, 2], me[p, x, 1, 1, 2, 3], me[p, x, 1, 1, 3, 1], me[p, x, 1, 1, 3, 2], me[p, x, 1, 1, 3, 3]}, 
{me[p, x, 1, 2, 1, 1], me[p, x, 1, 2, 1, 2] - 1, me[p, x, 1, 2, 1, 3], me[p, x, 1, 2, 2, 1], me[p, x, 1, 2, 2, 2], me[p, x, 1, 2, 2, 3], me[p, x, 1, 2, 3, 1], me[p, x, 1, 2, 3, 2], me[p, x, 1, 2, 3, 3]}, 
{me[p, x, 1, 3, 1, 1], me[p, x, 1, 3, 1, 2], me[p, x, 1, 3, 1, 3] - 1, me[p, x, 1, 3, 2, 1], me[p, x, 1, 3, 2, 2], me[p, x, 1, 3, 2, 3], me[p, x, 1, 3, 3, 1], me[p, x, 1, 3, 3, 2], me[p, x, 1, 3, 3, 3]}, 
{me[p, x, 2, 1, 1, 1], me[p, x, 2, 1, 1, 2], me[p, x, 2, 1, 1, 3], me[p, x, 2, 1, 2, 1] - 1, me[p, x, 2, 1, 2, 2], me[p, x, 2, 1, 2, 3], me[p, x, 2, 1, 3, 1], me[p, x, 2, 1, 3, 2], me[p, x, 2, 1, 3, 3]}, 
{me[p, x, 2, 2, 1, 1], me[p, x, 2, 2, 1, 2], me[p, x, 2, 2, 1, 3], me[p, x, 2, 2, 2, 1], me[p, x, 2, 2, 2, 2] - 1, me[p, x, 2, 2, 2, 3], me[p, x, 2, 2, 3, 1], me[p, x, 2, 2, 3, 2], me[p, x, 2, 2, 3, 3]}, 
{me[p, x, 2, 3, 1, 1], me[p, x, 2, 3, 1, 2], me[p, x, 2, 3, 1, 3], me[p, x, 2, 3, 2, 1], me[p, x, 2, 3, 2, 2], me[p, x, 2, 3, 2, 3] - 1, me[p, x, 2, 3, 3, 1], me[p, x, 2, 3, 3, 2], me[p, x, 2, 3, 3, 3]}, 
{me[p, x, 3, 1, 1, 1], me[p, x, 3, 1, 1, 2], me[p, x, 3, 1, 1, 3], me[p, x, 3, 1, 2, 1], me[p, x, 3, 1, 2, 2], me[p, x, 3, 1, 2, 3], me[p, x, 3, 1, 3, 1] - 1, me[p, x, 3, 1, 3, 2], me[p, x, 3, 1, 3, 3]}, 
{me[p, x, 3, 2, 1, 1], me[p, x, 3, 2, 1, 2], me[p, x, 3, 2, 1, 3], me[p, x, 3, 2, 2, 1], me[p, x, 3, 2, 2, 2], me[p, x, 3, 2, 2, 3], me[p, x, 3, 2, 3, 1], me[p, x, 3, 2, 3, 2] - 1, me[p, x, 3, 2, 3, 3]}, 
{me[p, x, 3, 3, 1, 1], me[p, x, 3, 3, 1, 2], me[p, x, 3, 3, 1, 3], me[p, x, 3, 3, 2, 1], me[p, x, 3, 3, 2, 2], me[p, x, 3, 3, 2, 3], me[p, x, 3, 3, 3, 1], me[p, x, 3, 3, 3, 2], me[p, x, 3, 3, 3, 3] - 1}
};
```

### Using NSolve to find x values for a given value of p

I finally get to the crux of my problem. I numerically solve by setting the determinant of the coefficient matrix to 0, and restrict x to between -10 and 10 (I have reasonable certainty that my solutions will not be outside this range for the range of p's I intend to work with).

```
xsolution[p_] := Sort[ NSolve[Det[coeff[p, x]] == 0. && (-10 <= x <= 10), x] ] (* Numerically solve which values of x yields Det[coeff]=0, and sorts the values. *)
```

Plotting what I believe are the 3 lowest values of x that I've found (as a function of p), I find that I have some odd-looking discontinuities, especially in the upper curve.

```
Plot[{
  xsolution[p][[1]][[1]][[2]],
  xsolution[p][[2]][[1]][[2]],
  xsolution[p][[3]][[1]][[2]]
  }, {p, -2, 2}, MaxRecursion -> 4, PlotPoints -> 5]
```

[image: Horizontal-axis is p-values, vertical axis is x-values]

What's more, I do not trust my results from NSolve! For example, the 2nd lowest value of x below (for p=1) does not yeild Det[coeff]=0 as expected. What am I doing wrong?!

```
xsolution[1]
```

yields output:

```
{{x -> -1.321793518956363}, {x -> -1.2613922782902645}, {x -> -0.5449889067896768}, {x -> -0.4556837316778105}, {x -> -0.455683729053839}, {x -> 0.34035978790527527}, {x -> 0.48514450207601595}, {x -> 0.682370748049176}, {x -> 0.6824136788022568}, {x -> 0.7017597948788745}, {x -> 0.7564607365305215}, {x -> 0.7565115382635393}, {x -> 1.3495866699741845}, {x -> 1.4698703476512056}, {x -> 1.4881232169456888}, {x -> 1.4881232372192312}, {x -> 1.690848785958313}, {x -> 1.69087512852734}, {x -> 2.5257845208148724}, {x -> 2.700249525479737}, {x -> 2.7003184957110764}, {x -> 2.7062611577155558}, {x -> 2.9030703703488534}, {x -> 2.903070397152075}, {x -> 2.9030704239717173}}
```

but

```
Det[coeff[1, -1.2613922782902645]]
```

gives

```
-28019.791238792383
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! I'm relatively inexperienced in Mathematica (as probably abundantly clear in my code above), so any help with my problems  - or advice on speeding up these clunky calculations - would be very much appreciated!! Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE. Thanks for taking the [tour]. Be sure you have learned about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable. Showing due diligence, giving brief context, including minimal working examples of code and data in [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) and so on help us to help you and in most cases inspires great answers. The site depends on participation, as you receive **give back:** vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.